# Informal speaking of most of us

Tags: grammar

Can I use "most of us does" reply to "I hate my life" in better way is it right to use it generally in informal speech???

Answer (score 1):

Most of us **do**.

“Most of us” is plural.

It’s a fine response to the utterance, “I hate my life.”

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **pro-verb**.

First person: I **hate** my life. Second person: Most of us **do**. [hate their lives.]

I just answered this question on ELL, so I will not rewrite it. You do not have to repeat a verb in many situations. You can use an auxiliary instead.

Here it is:

[non-repetition of main verb _ use of auxiliary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606909/is-it-right-pro-verb-refers-to-a-verb-not-a-verb-phrase/606915#606915)